# Tomcat no procesa mi xhtml

Tags: java, jsf, spring-boot, tomcat, maven

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con sprig-boot, jsf, tomcat y maven, cuando ejecuto la app con el comando `mvn-spring-boot:run` funciona perfectamente con mi tomcat embebido, pero cuando voy a mi tomcat en el servidor, cargo mi war y le doy en deploy mi xhtml se muestra en bruto, es decir literalmente con las etiquetas

Está es  mi configuración de jsf:

```
 @Bean
public static CustomScopeConfigurer scopeConfigurer() {
    CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hashMap.put("view", viewScope());
    configurer.setScopes(hashMap);
    return configurer;
}

/*
 * Below sets up the Faces Servlet for Spring Boot
 */
@Bean
public FacesServlet facesServlet() {
    return new FacesServlet();
}

/**
 * Configuración de JSF
 *
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean facesServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(
            facesServlet(), "*.xhtml");
    registration.setName("FacesServlet");
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: No sé cuál será exactamente el error, pero en mi experiencia el que se mostrara el XHTML sin procesar se debía a un fallo de inicialización, bien por falta de librerías o porque no se configuraba correctamente el `FacesServlet`. A falta de una solución más específica, yo revisaría que la versión del Tomcat (y del JVM) coincida y revisaría el log a ver si se registra el `FacesServlet` correctamente.